# Android setError validation still showing after Picking value from DatePicker.?

Tags: android, performance, validation, android-fragments, datepicker

I want Validation for a TextField. I have created a validation Successfully. If the TextField is empty, i am showing "Please Select Service Date". But here i have a Problem. I use to Pick the Date from DatePicker. When i pick the Date, it is filling the TextField. But still the Validation message is Showing "Please Select Service Date". But if i type anything inside the TextField its not showing the error. Could anyone please help me to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
String getService_date = service_dt.getText().toString();

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getService_date)) 
{
    service_dt.setError("Please Select Service Date");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once it got validated, setError(null);
Problem solves